# implement onClickListener for Horizontal ScrollView

Tags: android, android-imageview, horizontalscrollview, onitemclicklistener, picasso

I'm populating the Horizontal ScrollView using `Picasso` and the problem is that I can't properly implement `onClickListener` because those item views of list doesn't have any index.

**xml**:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/myGallery">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/channelsScrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**and the code**:

```
private void populateImages() {
    final List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();

    //getting list of urls
    for (int i = 0; i < ActivityLoading.dataChannelsArrayList.get(0).getChannelArrayList().size(); i++) {
        urls.add(getString(R.string.get_channels_img_host) + ActivityLoading.dataChannelsArrayList.get(0).getChannelArrayList().get(i).getId());
    }

    //add views to horizontal scrollView by the amount of urls
    myGallery = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.channelsScrollView);
    for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {
        myGallery.addView(insertPhoto(urls.get(i), i));
    }
}

public View insertPhoto(String path, int position) {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    final SquaredImageView squaredImageView = new SquaredImageView(getApplicationContext(), position);
    squaredImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    Picasso.with(this).load(path).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_small).into(squaredImageView);

    //I need to receive somehow the position of view pressed
    squaredImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             //this crashes here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), squaredImageView.id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    layout.addView(squaredImageView);
    return layout;
}
```

how to bind the index of `urls` List to respective `SquaredImageView` item in Horizontal ScrollView? Or maybe you can suggest better approach for `onClick`

Comment: Try setting the onClickListener for the layout instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:
Change the position parameter to final:
`public View insertPhoto(String path, final int position) {`

Then inside the onClickListener:
you have access to the position parameter.
`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "POSITION: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Option 2:
Set the tag of the squaredImageView:
`squaredImageView.setTag(position);`

Then in the onClickListener get that tag by calling:
`int location = (int)v.getTag();`